# jQuery.Deferred.exceptionHook shows warnings instead of errors in the console

Tags: javascript, jquery

About this piece of code: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/deferred/exceptionHook.js

Can anyone explain why jQuery.Deferred would show warnings (console.warn) in the console instead of just logging the error (console.error) when an error is thrown?

Also, why would they log only if the error is of type 'SyntaxError' for example, meaning the generic type 'Error', will not be logged, and will just vanish into the void when the deferred does not have a proper fail or error handler.

I think I understand why they just don't throw the error, because it would stop script execution, and they want to deferred flow to continue no matter what, but I can't understand why they do it this way.